# ChangeListener ObservableMap "oldValue" is copy of newValue

Tags: java, javafx

Question: Why is ChangeListener ObservableMap called with "oldValue" a copy of newValue?

```
    import javafx.beans.property.SimpleMapProperty;
    import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
    import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
    import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
    import javafx.collections.ObservableMap;

    public class ObservableMapExample {

        SimpleMapProperty map;

        class MyChangeListener implements ChangeListener> {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue> changed,
                    ObservableMap oldValue, ObservableMap  newValue) {
                System.out.println("changed "+changed+" old:"+oldValue+" new:"+newValue);
            }

        }

        ObservableMapExample() {
            map = new SimpleMapProperty();
            map.setValue(new SimpleMapProperty(FXCollections.observableHashMap()));
            map.addListener(new MyChangeListener());
            map.put("a", "1");
            map.put("b", "2");
            map.put("b", "3");

        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("ObservableMapExample");
            new ObservableMapExample();

        }
    }
```

Output:

```
ObservableMapExample
changed MapProperty [value: MapProperty [value: {a=1}]] old:MapProperty [value: {a=1}] new:MapProperty [value: {a=1}]
changed MapProperty [value: MapProperty [value: {a=1, b=2}]] old:MapProperty [value: {a=1, b=2}] new:MapProperty [value: {a=1, b=2}]
changed MapProperty [value: MapProperty [value: {a=1, b=3}]] old:MapProperty [value: {a=1, b=3}] new:MapProperty [value: {a=1, b=3}]
```

Comment: It's not called with a copy of the old value: It's called with `oldValue == newValue`. I couldn't find any info in the javadocs if this is the expected behaviour or not since it's not defined what it means for a property's value to be changed. If it means that some event happens that has the effect that a copy of the property's value prior to the event would no longer be considered equal to the new value then the observed behavior would indeed be correct...

Answer (score 0):

Because the value itself doesn't change, it is the same `SimpleMapProperty` that you set before adding key value pairs.

If you step through the code you will find this piece of code in `com.sun.javafx.binding.MapExpressionHelper`:

```
@Override
protected void fireValueChangedEvent(MapChangeListener.Change<? extends K, ? extends V> change) {
    listener.changed(observable, currentValue, currentValue);
}
```

The `ChangeListener` can only inform you that the map changed, but it can't tell you what changed, because the value is the map.

If however you call `setValue` again with a new `SimpleMapProperty` object, you will see that your `ChangeListener` indeed does get different objects for `oldValue` and `newValue`, because now the value itself has changed (not just modified).